# Get Object using id in flex?

Tags: apache-flex

Acctually

I want to remove Child from VBox , i have id of child , but i don't to have real object that i want to remove using removeChild function of VBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also want to set the "name" property on your component, such as :

```
myLabel.name = "LabelX";
myLabel.id = "LabelX"; // eventually
```

Then proceed to doing as the first answer said,

```
yourVBOX.removeChild( yourVBOX.getChildByName('LabelX') );
```

The thing to remember is to set the name as well as the ID, there is no such method as "getChildByID" :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
var elem:Type_of_E = this["constructed_id_of_E"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the name of your VBOX before runtime:

```
yourVBOX.removeChild( yourVBOX.getChildByName('yourChildID') );
```

Read more on:
[LiveDocs - Container - getChildByName](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/langref/mx/core/Container.html#getChildByName%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the id of the child to be removed, you have the real object. `id` attribute in `mxml` creates a public variable by it's value and store a reference to the object in that variable.

```
if(childId != null)
    vbox.removeChild(childId);
else
    trace("Normally this shouldn't happen in flex");


//or if you don't have VBox's id but you are sure that 
//the child is in fact is parented by a container:
    childId.parent.removeChild(childId);
```

Comment: I think he means he has the id as a string... as in, some algorithm in the program has given him the id of an element, not that he needs to know how to access controls from the class they are in.

Answer (score -1):

getChildByID:

```
this.getChildren()[id]
```

Comment: You mean `this.getChildren()[index]`, but he has the id, not the index.